# Halogen transformer replacement: safe to use 60w max to replace a 75w max?

Tags: halogen, transformer

I have a 120V to 12V 75W max transformer powering an Ikea Halogen light fixture. It seems to have burnt out.

All I can find in stores are 120V to 12V 60W max halogen transformers. The 75W max model I have found online shows a picture of 60W max model.

Is it safe to use these 60W max models to replace the 75W max model, or do I absolutely need a 75W max model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. What load is on the downstream side?

If there's only one 50W bulb, you should be fine. Two 35Ws? Need a bigger one.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the information I needed. Mine is a "spider" model with seven 10W, so I'll have to go with a 75w transformer.

Comment: You *may* also be able to re-wire the fitting so that 3x10W bulbs are on one transformer, and the other four on another. If you've got room and adequate cooling.